# Calling functions from different javascript files causing "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make some small changes to an existing vb.net website that was written by someone who no longer works for the company, but every time a javascript function is called from a script file other than the one it's defined in, I see "Uncaught Reference Error: undefined is not a function" in Chrome's console.

Some of the scripts are being loaded in the master file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/JSExtensions.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/GlobalUtilityFunctions.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
        jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);

        function resizeFrame() {
        }

</script>
```

And the rest are loaded in the page itself:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/GridCalcFunctions.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/InputEventHandlers.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/FocusHandlers.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/ProjectPageFunctions.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    });
    $(window).unload(function () {
        SaveOnExit();
    });

    function setPIDNumberLabel(ctlID, strVal) {
        var val = strVal;
        var ctl = top.$get(ctlID);
        if (ctl != null) {
            ctl.innerHTML = val;
        }
    }

</script>
```

GlobalUtilitesFunctions has no trouble accessing JSExtensions on other pages, but does here even though both are loaded in the master. I thought that must mean that the problem is caused by one of the files loaded on this page, but commenting them all out doesn't fix the issue.

As a specific example, GlobalUtilitiesFunctions contains this:

```
    function GetAttributeSelector(attName, attValue, attOperator,attNot) {
        attOperator = String.deNullValue(attOperator, "=");
        [more code]
    }
```

And I get an error that String.deNullValue is undefined, but over in JSExtenstions is:

```
String.iifValueIsNullOrEmpty = function (val, trueVal,falseVal) {
    falseVal = String.getArgValue(falseVal, val);
    if (String.isNullOrEmpty(val)) {
        return trueVal;
    }
    else {
        return falseVal;
    }
}
String.deNullValue = function (val,defaultVal) {
    var ret = "";
    defaultVal = String.iifValueIsNullOrEmpty(defaultVal,"");
    ret = String.iifValueIsNullOrEmpty(val,defaultVal);
    return ret;
}
```

I've also tried running the site on a server (instead of inside Visual Studio) without solving the problem. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Are all the files you loaded, loaded properly and have the methods that you are trying to use? If they are there make sure they are loaded first. You may be trying to use methods before they are loaded in their files.

Comment: Look into console stack-trace and try to resolve with method throws error. Then check that JavaScript with this methods is included to page that you actually see.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek All the pages are loaded and include the methods in question.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski The stack trace is how I got the information I put in the question. If I've left out something (entirely possible), then I'm afraid you'll have to be more specific in requesting it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) you can see this: 
"A variable declared (using var) within a JavaScript function becomes LOCAL to the function.

The variable gets a local scope: It can only be accessed from within that function."

try to define functions like

```
function deNullValue(val,defaultVal) {
   var ret = "";
   defaultVal = String.iifValueIsNullOrEmpty(defaultVal,"");
   ret = String.iifValueIsNullOrEmpty(val,defaultVal);
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, he's declaring String.deNullValue without the "var" keyword, making it a global variable, and then setting it equal to that function.

Comment: Yeah, after following these directions, the error message now reads "Uncaught Reference Error: [name of function] is not defined", which does not seem like a significant improvement.